# get text within a dom element but not it's child elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the author names from https://theartofliving.com/ultimate-learning-how-to-learn-reading-list/

I just need to run the script in the DevTools console and get the output.

Please look at the dom structure (simplified):

```
<li>
    (1991), George Leonard
    <a>
        <strong>
            Mastery
        </strong>
    </a>
    <span>
        The Keys to Success and
        Long-Term Fulfillment
    </span>
</li>
```

Here I am only interested in `(1991), George Leonard` which is inside `div.entry-content.single-page ol li`.

When I run:

```
var selects=document.querySelectorAll("div.entry-content.single-page ol li");
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
  console.log (selects[i].innerText);
}
```

It shows:

```
Mastery (1991), George Leonard (Summary)
The Keys to Success and Long-Term Fulfillment
176 pages. Rated 4.2 over 6,200 reviews on Goodreads.
```

I just want to get text inside `div.entry-content.single-page ol li` but not inside `div.entry-content.single-page ol li a` or `div.entry-content.single-page ol li span` or any child of the `li`.

How can I do that?

**Update 1:**

As per the request, the HTML actually looks like:

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/0452267560/?tag=whywhathow-20" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
            data-geniuslink="//buy.geni.us/Proxy.ashx?TSID=114250&amp;GR_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fdp%2F0452267560%2F%3Ftag%3Dwhywhathow-20"><strong>Mastery</strong></a>
        (1991), George Leonard (<a href="https://blinkist.o6eiov.net/r7nk3" target="_blank" class="external-url"
            rel="noopener noreferrer">Summary</a>)<br><span style="font-size: 0.8em; color: gray">The Keys to Success
            and Long-Term Fulfillment</span><br><span style="font-size: 0.6em; color: gray">176 pages. Rated 4.2 over
            6,200 reviews <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/81940.Mastery" target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer">on Goodreads</a>.</span></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/0671212095/?tag=whywhathow-20" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
            data-geniuslink="//buy.geni.us/Proxy.ashx?TSID=114250&amp;GR_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fdp%2F0671212095%2F%3Ftag%3Dwhywhathow-20"><strong>How
                to Read a Book</strong></a> (1940), Mortimer J. Adler (<a
            href="https://theartofliving.com/how-to-read-a-book-summary/" class="highlight"><strong>FREE</strong>
            Summary</a>)<br><span style="font-size: 0.8em; color: gray">The Classic Guide to Intelligent
            Reading</span><br><span style="font-size: 0.8em; color: gray"><em>THE classic guide to reading faster,
                deeper and more effectively than you ever realised was possible – by deep-thinkers, philosophers and
                life-long learners, M. Adler and C. van Doren.</em></span><br><span
            style="font-size: 0.6em; color: gray">426 pages. Rated 4.0 over 16,300 reviews <a
                href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/567610.How_to_Read_a_Book" target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer">on Goodreads</a>.</span></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/1847922929/?tag=whywhathow-20" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
            data-geniuslink="//buy.geni.us/Proxy.ashx?TSID=114250&amp;GR_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fdp%2F1847922929%2F%3Ftag%3Dwhywhathow-20"><strong>The
                Art of Memory</strong></a> (1966), Frances A. Yates<br><span style="font-size: 0.6em; color: gray">464
            pages. Rated 4.2 over 1,300 reviews <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/245831.The_Art_of_Memory"
                target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">on Goodreads</a>.</span></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/0143113100/?tag=whywhathow-20" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
            data-geniuslink="//buy.geni.us/Proxy.ashx?TSID=114250&amp;GR_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fdp%2F0143113100%2F%3Ftag%3Dwhywhathow-20"><strong>The
                Brain That Changes Itself</strong></a> (2007), Norman Doidge (<a
            href="https://theartofliving.com/the-brain-that-changes-itself-norman-doidge/"
            class="highlight"><strong>FREE</strong> Summary</a>)<br><span style="font-size: 0.8em; color: gray">Stories
            of Personal Triumph from the Frontiers of Brain Science</span><br><span
            style="font-size: 0.8em; color: gray"><em>An informative and readable journey into the history, science and
                consequences of recent research in&nbsp;neuroplasticity&nbsp;– the brain’s incredible ability to change
                and reorganise itself – by psychiatrist, psychoanalyst and researcher, Norman
                Doidge.</em></span><br><span style="font-size: 0.6em; color: gray">427 pages. Rated 4.2 over 29,400
            reviews <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/570172.The_Brain_That_Changes_Itself" target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer">on Goodreads</a>.</span></li>

....

</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, this should do it:

```
console.log(selects[i].childNodes[1].textContent.trim());
```

Getting the first `childNode` and then its `textContent`.
Added trim() to get remove trailing and leading whitespace.

Comment: The text is not actually in the first node. I just put it for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you very much. `console.log (selects[i].childNodes[1].textContent.trim());` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the other elements first.

```js
document.querySelector("li > a").remove();
document.querySelector("li > span").remove();

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.innerText);
});
```

```html
<li>
    (1991), George Leonard
    <a>
        <strong>
            Mastery
        </strong>
    </a>
    <span>
        The Keys to Success and
        Long-Term Fulfillment
    </span>
</li>
```

Or in the URL you provided:

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content.single-page > ol > li");
const removala = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content.single-page > ol > li > a");
const removalb = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content.single-page > ol > li > span");
removala.forEach(item => item.remove());
removalb.forEach(item => item.remove());
let result = [];
targets.forEach(item => result.push(item.innerText.replace("()", "").trim()));
```

Comment: Please test the code in the given URL (with the help of DevTools).

Comment: @blueray just did.